# Dual-Monitor with Radeon 7970 HD Graphics Card?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, radeon

I'm trying to setup dual 23'' dell ultrasharp monitors in 12.04 and have run into a few difficulties. I'm running a Radeon 7970 HD graphics card, and am using the latest catalyst (12-6) at the moment.

Unfortunately, my right monitor is the only screen which is correctly configured, and my left monitor is at an extremely low resolution (640x480) and I'm having difficulty configuring it.

I've also run into [this](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware), which basically says that my graphics card is only "officially" supported with catalyst 12-1. But according to this [source](http://www.x-drivers.com/catalog/drivers/video_cards/companies/amd/models/catalyst_linux/23776.html), the 7970 HD is not supported.

My questions are:

1. What does officially supported mean and should I NOT be using the latest catalyst (12-6)?
2. Has anyone run into this problem before with a Radeon 7970 HD card attempting a dual monitor setup? What are your solutions if any?

At the moment, it hangs on boot saying:
"stopping system v runlevel compatability"
I did in fact edit my xorg.conf file for dual monitors. The one that's autogenerated was not working whatsoever. When I revert to the autogenerated configuration file it boots fine, but then dual monitors stop working (one of the monitors is at a really low resolution and is a mirroring the upper-left corner of the other one). I'm totally at a loss.

I'd really love to get this working and I've spend nearly a week installing and un-installing different drivers and versions of Catalyst. Any info about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone is interested I can share my xorg.conf file located in /etc/X11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was eventually to update to 12.10. I'm currently on 13.04 now, but it seems to be a non-issue with this release. It's a shame that I never got this working on 12.04, though.